# Set allocated Mat with raw data OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a `uchar* raw` from an API which represents an image raw data. The width, height and number of channels of this `raw` is already known. I have already pre-allocated an cv::Mat (OpenCV) with this width and height.

My question is - how is it possible to set raw into this cv::Mat. I would like to copy raw into cv::Mat instead of just switching pointers. Is there a function to accomplish this or I need to do so manually myself?

Comment: cv::Mat(size, CV_8UC1, raw).copyTo (yourPreallocatedImage);

Answer (score 1):

I guess it isn't the most sophisticated way but it should work:

`uchar* raw;
  cv::Mat image(size, type, raw);
  image = image.clone();`

Answer (score -1):

```
cv::Mat mat(cv::Size(width, height), CV_8UC1, raw, cv::Mat::AUTO_STEP);

copiedImage = mat.clone();
```